# How to select a particular value/attribute in json data via python?

Tags: python, json

I have some json data , which I want to load and inspect in python. I know python has few different ways to handle json. if i want to see what is the author name in following  json data, how can directly select the value of name inside author in following json, without having to iterate , if there are multiple topic/blog in the data?

```
{
  "topic": 
  {
     "language": "JSON",
  },
 "blog":[
  {
   "author" : {
       "name" : "coder"
   }
  }]
}
```

Comment: `data['blog'][0]['author']['name']` should do. `data` is the loaded `json` file. For example if using `data = json.load(file)` (should use `with open("file_name.json") as file:` and `import json`)

Comment: @Matiiss - thanks. one more follow up question, is it possible to select a particular author if there are multiple author attributes in the data say => data['blog'][0]['author']['name'] == 'coder'

Comment: I can't think of an easy way, the only is to just loop over the `"blog"` list until You find the name